# How do I get the Status of the interface network?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

How do I get the Network Status on MacOS?

I tried changing the second argument of `SCNetworkInterfaceGetExtendedConfiguration(interface, kSCEntNetEthernet)` in various ways, but all results were `nil`.

And I also tried `SCNetworkInterfaceGetConfiguration(interface)` and got the result below:

```
Optional({
    JoinModeFallback =     (
        DoNothing
    );
    PowerEnabled = 1;
    RememberJoinedNetworks = 1;
    Version = 3000;
})
```

but it has no status which I wanted.

I would like to programmatically get the status as Connected information in the following image, which can be found in System Preferences > Network.

[image]

Comment: What Apple would like you to do, in general, is just perform network transactions and see what happens. If there is no network available you'll find out soon enough that way.

Comment: @matt thank you comment. I'm making an application to switch networks with `SCNetworkSetSetServiceOrder`, and I want to display the network status on the application side.

Comment: Is this it? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1517046-scbondinterfacecopystatus?language=objc